# What are nowadays ASP.NET IDE alternatives to visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, ide

I have some problem about crash in my visual studio 2010.
Often, when i modify a page, the content become blank and i can't modify , it crash or i have to reload the application.
I want try an alternative.

Which software has the same functionalities ? Or even works better ?

What i have tried until now :

- Visual Studio 2010

What i search :

- Something that works fine and may free edition

Comment: How about the latest, free community edition? https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

Comment: Let me try it , thanks

Comment: Why people put -1 ? ...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: That's why.....

Comment: this is pretty old, but in case someone still wonders, id suggest https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative you can use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (especially if you plan to use .Net Core).

It's a rewrite of the IDE using Node Javascript behind the [Electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(software_framework)) framework. Although you have not all the Visual Studio features, this IDE is **very fast** and highly customisable with a [bunch of plugins](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery). Another advantage is that you are no more limited to use it on a Windows platform. (It works equally well on Linux for instance.)

You can check documentation from Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-app-using-vscode).

Nevertheless, I'm using Visual Studio for many years now and it has always been a great IDE. Although it may become very slow if not properly configured. I personally find Visual Studio 2017 more responsive than its successor. So another option is simply to check your IDE is properly configured. Increasing computer memory is also a great thing to do when using VS, as well as using a SSD. I personally still thing that Visual Studio is one of the best IDE out there although it is using sometime much computer resources.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So usefull. i will try vs code meanwhile i use visual studio 2010

Answer (score 2):

You can try SharpDevelop.Its lightweight and ease to use http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/Default.aspx